# How do you increase the colorrange for pyplots contour-graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, contour

I'm trying to plot an error function as a contour. The approximation I'm using has two variables which each produce an average error:
[image: wireframe of function]

I'm now trying to plot this as a contour:

```
def contour(pa, pm, data):

    print("Plotting Contour")
    plt.xlabel("alpha")
    plt.ylabel("m")

    plt.contourf(pa, pm, data)
    plt.colorbar()

    plt.show()
```

This produces this contour graph:
[image: Contour Graph]

Unfortunately I'm loosing a lot of detail in the valley. How do I increase the colorrange or is there an option to just color everything above a certain threshold yellow?

Answer (score 0):

Use **plt.pcolor**, **vmin** and **vmax**.
Read about it in [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html) - explains it simpler then I can.

Comment: You can also use vmin and vmax for contour, as well as adding more contour levels.  You can also change the norm to a logarithmic norm if you want more color detail in the valley.

Comment: Well, yes, I guess that does something usefull, I got to give that to you, but not really.

Comment: @JodyKlymak If you set a vmax or vmin for contour anything outside that is just white. How would you set the scale to log? I didn't read about this anywhere in the docs O.O

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you :)